# UI for uninstall

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, installation, uninstallation

The installer is created using a Visual Studio 2010 Setup project.  The Setup project provides a way for developers to customize the UI during installation.  Is there a way to do the same for uninstallation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a project to your solution called (for example) PostUnInstall.

Right-click the setup project, select "Custom Actions".

Add a custom action to UnInstall, pointing to "PostInstall project output".
Uncheck "Installer class" (very important, or it won't work).

At the end of the uninstall, your PostUnInstall will be executed.

Comment: I have figured out how to add a custom action to the uninstall operation.  What I want to know is how to provide a UI for this custom action.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. Your PostInstall project should be a standard Windows Forms application - PostInstall.exe, which can have whatever UI you desire, or are you trying to replace the actual Installer UI?

Comment: Can the PostInstall project be a WPF application?  Also, I'm not trying to replace the installer UI.

Comment: I've never tried it, but I see no reason why not. Give it a try!